# jQuery Ajax request to Struts2 action class always returns 200 ok, but error event is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I am new to *Struts2* and I'm going to send set of form data to struts action class.

This is my Ajax code in jsp

```js
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "getProjectPost",
    data: { "language" : langArr , "clientId": clientId, "projectName": projectName, "projectType": projectType},
    traditional: true,
    success:
        function()
        {
     alert("Success");
        },
    error: 
    function()
        {
      alert("Error");
        }
});
```

This is my `struts.xml`:

```xml
<package name="projectPost" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="getProjectPost" class="com.test.ProjectPostAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">
        <param name="location">/webpages/Client/Success.jsp</param >
        </result>
        <result name="failure">./LandingPage.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">./error.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Ajax request returns 200 OK, but always alert "Error". I referred many articles but still not get proper solution

Comment: Have you checked response in Console Log Network, please check response string is empty or not?

Comment: alerted the response in error event of ajax. it give {"readyState":0, "response Text":"", "status":0, "statusText":"error"}

Comment: response Text should not be null when readyState is 4

Comment: So what can I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending result `redirect` while doing ajax request. Ajax request won't redirect you to another location, it will stay on the same page when request was made.

Change

```
<result name="success" type="redirect">
```

to

```
<result name="success" type="dispatcher">
```

The `dispatcher` is default result type that will render JSP at the specified location and write response HTML to the out. This response could be easily loaded with jQuery to any `div` available on the same page.

Comment: tried and alerted the response in error event of ajax. it give {"readyState":0, "response Text":"", "status":0, "statusText":"error"}

Comment: It is working.The problem was I didn't call e.preventDefault() inside of my event handler. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible that you get response 200 OK still error callback is executed in ajax request because response from requested url is empty.

So you have to check server side code why response is empty or contact to back-end developer for same.

For more calcification you can use below code.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "getProjectPost",
    data: { "language" : langArr , "clientId": clientId, "projectName": projectName, "projectType": projectType},
    success: function(data){
        console.log("in success function");
        alert("Error:: " + data);
    },
    error: function(data){
         console.log("in error function");
         alert("Error :: "+ data);
    }
});
```

Comment: alerted the response in error event of ajax. it give {"readyState":0, "response Text":"", "status":0, "statusText":"error"}. So what can I do now